# How to Send email in php without any submission of form?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am working on script in php, in which i want to send mail to particular address  without submitting any form.

```
    <?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

so please anybody help me how to send email to email address without submitting any form in  php.

Comment: Without submitting means without click also ?

Comment: Add code on page refresh or cron file.

Comment: When do you want to send the email? On Page load? at a certain time?

Comment: Your current php script is already sending email if that is run in browser or from php command line. In case you are not receiving email on the other end, it might be that server is not configured with sendmail (php uses sendmail), There can be other reasons as well ; like your SMTP server reputation is low and the email is going in spam or getting purged by email firewall. In such situations, you can try using PHP mailer library and your are free to use your some other SMTP details.

Comment: could you please let me then when you want send the mail, what is the exact requirement so you will get precise solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a form to send an email. By calling the function

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

You automatically send the email. A form is used to collect the information you want to send. If you already have the information, all you have to do is fill in the information in your four variables: `$to`,`$subject`, `$message`, and `$headers` and then use the function:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Let me know if that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your script to execute on form submission then you have two other options.

Either put a link to this page in another page of your application.

```
<a href="path-to-your-mail-sending-file">Send Email</a>
```

or redirect to this page from another php script:

```
header("Location: path-to-your-mail-sending-file");
```

Also you should consider using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) as it is more customizable and reliable than the default `mail` function

Comment: Clicking an anchor will submit the form! Redirecting will submit the form or in fact assumes the form has been submitted in order to run some PHP.

Comment: Yes but these methods do not require a form. You can redirect to a PHP page without doing it from a form. I think OP wants to avoid using a form. At least that's how I understand the question

Comment: Tell me how you cause an `<a....` tag to do anythig without a form? I am interested

Comment: @RiggsFolly how redirecting to a page will submit a form without triggering submit button??

Comment: @JiteshNK Ok bad wording on my behalf, it in fact causes another script/page to run, without submitting this one. But if OP does not want to submit a form they wont want to run another page/script

Comment: @RiggsFolly
Let's say we have two files: send_email.php which contains OP's code and file.php that contains: <a href="send_email.php"></a>
This way send_email.php will be executed without any form submission, in the exact same way that the very same script could be executed by an AJAX request

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's okay! just to avoid confusion i had asked you

Comment: @dimlucas Good point: If he wants to send an email containing **nothing of any interest** (see email content) to `someone` and `someoneelse` and `myboss` **that would work nicely** Although why he wants to send an email to my boss I cannot see. **he will not be very impressed with this email** Although maybe his boss is easier to please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cronjob that will be triggered at a certain time.
If your hosting doesn't provide access to cronjobs, you can use:

https://www.setcronjob.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try with Ajax

```
$(document).load(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: send_email.php,
            type:'POST',
            data:
            {
                email: email_address,
                message: message
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert('Email Sent');
            }               
        });
    });
```

put your email code in send_email.php

Comment: **still not working even not giving any error msg !**                                               
`<script>
$(document).load(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: mailer.php,
            type:'POST',
            data:
            {
                to: to,
                message: message
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert('Email Sent');
            }               
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: nandhakumar: You have opened a nasty can of worms now. You are going to have to write the whole script for this guy now, including the PHP code to run on the server. I hope he actually bothers to accept your answer when you are finished in about an hour or so